# have problem with menu item click event in flex actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, menuitem

i go through the code several times but can not figure out the problem help required here is the code;

```
 menuItems      = [{label:"60 Minutes View" , type:"radio", toggled:"true"},{label:"30 Minutes View" , type:"radio"},{label:"20 Minutes View" , type:"radio"},{label:"15 Minutes View" , type:"radio"},{label:"10 Minutes View" , type:"radio"},{label:"6 Minutes View" , type:"radio"},{label:"5 Minutes View" , type:"radio"}];

menu      = Menu.createMenu( parentInstance, menuItems, false );
menu.addEventListener(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK,menuClick);

protected function menuClick(evt:MenuEvent):void
  {
   Alert.show("here is    " + evt.item + "  23");
   switch (evt.label)
   {
    case "60 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(60);
     break;
    case "30 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(30);
     break;
    case "20 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(30);
     break;
    case "15 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(15);
     break;
    case "10 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(10);
     break;
    case "6 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(6);
     break;
    case "5 Minutes View":
     this.ChangeLayout(5);
     break;
    default:
     break;

   }//end switch
  }//end function
```

but is doesn't even capture the item click event .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing `evt.item` / `evt.label` to `evt.currentTarget.item` / `evt.currentTarget.label` or `evt.target.item` / `evt.target.label`

---

also, just a suggestion, if you create constants for your string objects your code will be easier to debug as nothing will be caused by spelling mistakes and the compiler will pick up on a mistyped constant in addition to allowing you to edit your string only once.

so instead of:

```
menuItems = [{label:"60 Minutes View" , type:"radio", toggled:"true"}];

switch (evt.currentTarget.label)
       {
       case "60 Minutes View":...
```

you could create a constant:

```
private static const 60_MIN_VIEW:String = "60 Minutes View";

menuItems = [{label:60_MIN_VIEW , type:"radio", toggled:"true"}];

switch (evt.currentTarget.label)
       {
       case 60_MIN_VIEW:...
```